# When I modify DataGridView, It gives system.invalidoperationexception cross-thread operation not valid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a database which is SQLite and I have a windows form application. There is a `DataGridView` in that form which have got 4 columns. I have use a timer to update my `DataGridView` contents.

But Every time I clear the `DataGridView` and then I fill it because I have to sort them by date. If I don't use `.Rows.Clear()` and `.Refresh` it adds the same content over and over again. So I use them.

I use different way like comment lines, but problem is

```
system.invalidoperationexception cross-thread operation not valid
```

I have tried all solution of StackOverflow and whole internet, but all the way gives my same exception.

What is my problem. I have called this method directly and I have called it as a thread, It gave me same exception. It gives me exception when I use `DataGridView`. For example, in this code block, it gives in `dgwIslemGemisi.DataSource=dt;`

```
private void guncellemeIslemGecmisiGoster()
{
    dt = db.TumGuncellemeIslemGecmisiGetir();


    dgwIslemGecmisi.DataSource = dt;
    dgwIslemGecmisi.Update();

    dgwIslemGecmisi.Rows.Clear();
    dgwIslemGecmisi.Refresh();

    ////Set AutoGenerateColumns False
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    ////Set Columns Count
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.ColumnCount = 4;

    ////Add Columns
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[0].Name = "islemAdi";
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[0].HeaderText = "İşlem Adı";
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "islemAdi";

    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[1].HeaderText = "İşleme Başlangıç Tarihi";
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[1].Name = "islemBaslangicTarihi";
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "islemBaslangicTarihi";

    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[2].Name = "islemBitisTarihi";
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[2].HeaderText = "İşlemin Tamamlanma Tarihi";
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "isleminBitisTarihi";

    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[3].Name = "islemDurumu";
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[3].HeaderText = "İşlem Durumu";
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "islemDurumu";
    //dgwIslemGecmisi.DataSource = dt;


    //for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    //{

    //    string durum = "Başarısız";
    //    if (dt.Rows[i]["islemDurumu"].ToString() == "1")
    //    {
    //        durum = "Başarılı";
    //    }

    //    dgwIslemGecmisi.Rows.Add(new object[] {
    //        dt.Rows[i]["islemAdi"].ToString(),
    //        dt.Rows[i]["islemBaslangicTarihi"].ToString(),
    //        dt.Rows[i]["islemBitisTarihi"].ToString(),
    //        durum

    //    });


    //}
    dt.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You must be calling this `guncellemeIslemGecmisiGoster()` in a background thread. If you fill the `DataTable` in a background thread you need to either wait for the thread to exit and then set the `DataSource` or call `Invoke` while in the background thread.

Comment: I have call Inove like belove code block. There is no exception or error. If there is any logic or programmatic problem. You can write. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution of exception.

```
private void guncellemeIslemGecmisiGoster()
        {
            dt = db.TumGuncellemeIslemGecmisiGetir();



            dgwIslemGecmisi.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwIslemGecmisi.DataSource = dt));
            dgwIslemGecmisi.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwIslemGecmisi.Update()));



            dt.Dispose();
        }
```